# Я вам представил режиссера номера, но(,) мне кажется, он не запечатлелся

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Из Национального корпуса русского языка:

> Видите ли, Евгений Исаакович, благодарю вас, **но мне кажется**, я уже… решил этот кроссворд.
>
> Я вам представил режиссера номера, **но мне кажется**, он не запечатлелся в вашей голове.

Можно ли не ставить запятую после "но", как это сделано выше? Когда запятая обязательна? В корпусе есть примеры как с запятой, так и без нее.

Розенталь пишет, что запятая необязательна, когда "но" стоит в начале предложения (после точки). Пункта о необязательности запятой в середине предложения пока не находил.

Comment: Можно ссылку, где Розенталь об этом пишет?

Comment: @oleedd Примечание в самом конце, п. 2: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_25.htm#ppp_5 Вот тут написано, что вводные сочетания выделяются запятыми, если их можно опустить без изменения структуры предложения. Я думаю, в моих примерах их можно опустить.

Comment: Да, это очень важный принцип.

Comment: Примечание: Гораздо естественней без запятой, потому что оно очень похоже на "но мне кажется, что". Поэтому и запятой в примерах нет. В примере Розенталя не так. "Но я вижу" — не сильно естественно, так как не в прямом смысле видит, а замечает, думает, полагает: *Но я вижу, вам не нравится эта работа.* Тут явный оттенок вводности, и варианты примерно равносильны (в плане удачности). А "кажется" — всегда в прямом смысле и естественно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно не ставить.

Тогда не будет вводного предложения и пропущено слово "что":
*Я вам представил режиссера номера, но мне кажется, (что) он не запечатлелся в вашей голове.* || Этот вариант гораздо естественней звучит. "Но" относится к "кажется".

При вводном предложении можно добавить слово "как" и это ни на что не влияет:
*Я вам представил режиссера номера, но, (как) мне кажется, он не запечатлелся в вашей голове.* || Перед "мне" обязательна пауза при чтении.

Ещё вводное предложение "мне кажется" можно переставить:
*Я вам представил режиссера номера, но он, мне кажется, не запечатлелся в вашей голове.*

> Когда запятая обязательна?

Когда "но" относится не к "кажется", а к следующей фразе.

Нет разницы, начало это или середина предложения. Просто в начале предложения примыкание союза к вводной конструкции можно наблюдать чаще, так как союз часто свободен, раз не соединяет два простых предложения.

В таких случаях нужно смотреть, к чему именно относится союз. Часто есть два варианта, и решает автор.

Розенталь ([ссылка](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_25.htm)):

> Постановка запятой позволяет разграничить вводное сочетание и независимое предложение в составе бессоюзного сложного предложения.
>
> *Но, **я вижу**, вам это не подходит* (вводное предложение).
> *Но **я вижу**, вам это не подходит* (бессоюзное сложное предложение).

Comment: Спасибо. Только что увидел пункт у Розенталя об этом. Можете добавить в ответ, если хотите. (http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_25.htm#ppp_6) *Постановка запятой позволяет разграничить вводное сочетание и независимое предложение в составе бессоюзного сложного предложения. Но, **я вижу**, вам это не подходит (вводное предложение). — Но **я вижу**, вам это не подходит (бессоюзное сложное предложение).*

Comment: Добавлено. Разница в том, что при вводном предложении после "но" обязательна пауза при чтении.

Comment: @athlonusm Здесь интересно - интервью с Розенталем: https://gailochka.livejournal.com/142469.html